# Where to find household financial data for my research

Tags: data-request, finance

I am a programming student, I want to make a financial application for my project. The application works by gathering user's income and expenses to create a prediction about their financial status next month.

My project is to create research about the application I want to make. The problem is, I need some real data to calculate the accuracy of my application. The data I need are income and expenses of some people for at least 5 months. Does anybody know where I can possibly find this kind of data, or how can I make a survey to get this data?

In addition, I can't wait for 5 months to gather the data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you can use united states residents, you are looking for the survey of income and program participation.  this microdata set contains *monthly* income about persons, families, and households.  enjoy!

http://www.asdfree.com/search/label/survey%20of%20income%20and%20program%20participation%20%28sipp%29